# Restarting Application in Jetty Server

Tags: java, jetty, jmx

I have to restart my  application which I have copied in the webapps folder in jetty. Is there any command which can restart my application

Comment: Is it on linux or windows.. ?

Comment: @Soumen Mukherjee i need to restart the application in both linux and windows